# How do I make TypeScript recognize the type of an argument to a function based on the return?

Tags: typescript

```
function isType(
    value: any,
    type: 'undefined'|'object'|'boolean'|'number'|'bigint'|'string'|'symbol'|'function'
): boolean {
    return typeof value === type;
}

function getDefaultIfUndefined<T>(value: T|undefined, defaultValue: T): T
{
    return isType(value, 'undefined') ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

TypeScript complains that the return type of getDefaultIfUndefined() is T|undefined not just T. But it will always be T because the ternary ensures "defaultValue" will be returned if "value" is undefined.

TypeScript has no problem when it is written like this though:

```
function getDefaultIfUndefined<T>(value: T|undefined, defaultValue: T): T
{
    return typeof value === 'undefined' ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it! That wasn't easy, look:

```js
interface TypeMap {
    undefined: undefined;
    object: object;
    boolean: boolean;
    number: number;
    bigint: bigint;
    string: string;
    symbol: symbol;
    function: (...args: any[]) => any;
}
function isType<T extends keyof TypeMap>(
    value: any,
    type: T 
): value is TypeMap[T] {
    return typeof value === type;
}
```